# django-background-tasks migrations on heroku

Tags: django, heroku, migration, background-task

I am trying to migrate dajngo-background-tasks on my app hosted in heroku. Migrations worked normally locally but when I tried to run:

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

It returned 'No migrations to apply'

1. I've added 'background_task', to INSTALLED_APPS
2. I ran

   ```
   heroku run python manage.py makemigrations background_task
   ```

   And it created the required migrations
3. I even tried running

   ```
   heroku run python manage.py migrate background_task
   ```

   causing "CommandError: App 'background_task' does not have migrations."

PS: One thing I noticed is that when running migrate locally I get this text

```
Apply all migrations: admin, background_task, auth, contenttypes, sessions, <my_app>
```

But when I run it on the server I get

```
Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, <my_app>
```

Every form of help will be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to missing migrations in the django-background-tasks package. This issue has been fixed in the latest version. If you install 1.1.9 the deployment to heroku should work.

Answer (score 3):

You must not run makemigrations via heroku run. You must run it locally, commit the resulting migrations and push them to heroku, then run them there.

Comment: Did that too. Did not work. Still says 'No migrations to apply'. Tried running process_tasks just to be sure and still got the same old error when background_task didn't migrate. It's basically <traceback blah blah blah> 'column background_task.verbose_name does not exist
LINE 1: ...sk"."task_params", "background_task"."task_hash", "backgroun...'

Comment: EDIT:
Reached to the conclusion that some migrations concerning the background_task were made, but when I run 'heroku run python manage.py process_tasks' it shows me this error 'column background_task.verbose_name does not exist LINE 1: ...sk"."task_params", "background_task"."task_hash", "backgroun...'